Firebase Cloud Messaging / Function - Not getting Push notification sound on IOS devices
I have created a Firebase function using Node.js 20 to send push notifications to iOS devices through Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for my Swift app. The messages are successfully sent and received on the device, but the notification sound is not playing. This happens both when using a custom sound and the 'default' sound in the payload.
Issue:
I receive the notification on the device, but there is no sound.
When sending test messages directly from the Firebase Console, notifications with sound work perfectly. The default notfication sound is playing on the ios device.
What I’ve checked:
I’m sure the app has the correct permissions set for notifications.
Notifications sent via Firebase Console include sound, so permissions should be in place.
Here’s my Firebase Cloud Function code in index.js:
Here is the index.js code:
// Import the Firebase SDK for Google Cloud Functions.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Sends notifications to all users when a new message is posted.
exports.sendNotifications = 
functions.firestore.document('CustomersWithoutBooking/{messageId}').onCreate(
 async (snapshot) => {
// Notification details.
const text = snapshot.data().text;


const payload = {
notification: {
title: `Dropin  trenger hjelp !!`,
body: `Kunde står i resepsjonen og trenger hjelp. Husk å markere at du har tatt 
kunden`,
 },
  android: {
    notification: {
    sound: 'default',  // Android default sound
    }
  },
  apns: {
    headers: {
       'apns-priority': '10',  // High priority for immediate delivery
   },
   payload: {
   aps: {
       alert: {
         title: `Dropin  trenger hjelp !!`,
         body: `Kunde står i resepsjonen og trenger hjelp. Husk å markere at du har 
  tatt kunden`,
       },
       sound: 'default', //'serious-strike.m4r', // Ensure the sound key is properly set for iOS
          contentAvailable: true,
        }
      }
    }
  };


      // Fetch the device tokens from 'Behandlere' collection.
     const allTokensSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('Behandlere').get();
     const tokens = [];

    // Get the list of device tokens.
      // Collect all the PushIDs from documents.
      allTokensSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       const data = doc.data();
        if (data.PushID && Array.isArray(data.PushID)) {
          tokens.push(...data.PushID);  // Push all tokens into the array
       }
  });

   if (tokens.length > 0) {
     // Send notifications to all tokens using sendEachForMulticast.
     const responses = await admin.messaging().sendEachForMulticast({
       tokens: tokens,
       notification: payload.notification,
     });

     // Cleanup invalid tokens after sending notifications
     await cleanupTokens(responses, tokens);
     functions.logger.log('Notifications have been sent and tokens cleaned up.');
      }
    }
  );

  // Cleans up the tokens that are no longer valid.
  async function cleanupTokens(response, tokens) {
    const tokensDelete = [];
    response.responses.forEach((result, index) => {
       const error = result.error;
      if (error) {
        functions.logger.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
            error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
          const deleteTask = 
  admin.firestore().collection('fcmTokens').doc(tokens[index]).delete();
          tokensDelete.push(deleteTask);
        }
      }
    });
    await Promise.all(tokensDelete);
  }

Here is my package.json file:
{
 "name": "friendlychat-codelab",
 "description": "Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions codelab",
 "dependencies": {
   "@google-cloud/vision": "^3.0.0", 
   "firebase-admin": "^11.10.0",   
   "firebase-functions": "^4.4.0",  
   "util": "^0.12.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "eslint": "^7.23.0",
   "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1"
 },
 "engines": {
   "node": "20"
 },
 "private": true

}

"sound" : "default" should be inside the "notification" key as well. This JSON should work.
{
    "to": "myToken",
    "notification": {
         "body": "test",
         "title": "test",
         "sound": "default"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}

Complete json:
let message = {
    notification: {
        'body': 'This is the message the user sees',
        'sound': "default"
    },
    data: {
        'param1': 'specify some extra data here',
    },
    // Apple specific settings
    apns: {
        headers: {
            'apns-priority': '10',
        },
        payload: {
            aps: {
                sound: 'default',
            }
        },
    },
    android: {
      priority: 'high',
      notification: {
          sound: 'default',
      }
    },
    token: 'target FCM token goes here',
};


First of all, thanks for trying to help. I tried adding sound: 'default' to under notification, but then there is no notification at all.

If i use this payload:
const payload = {
notification: {
title: 'TITLE',  // Title of the notification
body: TESTBODY,  // Body of the notification
sound: "default",  // Default sound for iOS
}
};
The notification isnt received on the ios device at all.

If i change sendEachForMulticast method for send it works with sound.  I dont understand why.  I have to send one and one message.
